# Intersect between two date intervals

Tags: mysql

I need to find intersect between to date intervals for example

I have one date

```
2015-01-01 and 2015-03-01
```

and second value

```
2015-01-01 and 2015-01-15
```

I wanna get results `15`. So how many days of second date is included in first date range?
Any ideas how to do it with MySql?

Comment: Select datediff (least(end1,end2),greatest(start1,start2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can use the following SQL statement to get what you need:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(LEAST('2015-03-01 23:59:59','2015-01-15 23:59:59'),GREATEST('2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-01-01 00:00:00'))+1 AS days;
+------+
| days |
+------+
|   15 |
+------+
```

This will get the date difference in days using DATEDIFF

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF('2015-01-01 -2015-03 ', ' 2015-01-01 -2015-01-15 23:59:59') AS days; yes but i have two intervals  something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` for condition like below:

```
SELECT (CASE
            WHEN '2015-01-01'>= '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-15'<='2015-03-01'
            THEN DATEDIFF('2015-01-15','2015-01-01')+1
            ELSE 'out of range'
        END) AS days;
```

You can specify your own else condition and date range.